# Как централизованно управлять конфигурациями приложения?

Tags: php, yii, configuration

Привет! Имеется довольно непростой проект, написанный на php, используя реймворк Yii. Он развернут в нескольких регионах, на разных серверах, для каждого региона свои индивидуальные настройки.

Постоянно лазить по серверам через ssh мне кажется утомительным, и думается мне, что умные чуваки давно уже придумали какую-то штуку, которая позволила бы в одном месте управлять конфигурациями как минимум одного приложения для разных его инстансов. Видимо, искать Я не умею. Ткните носом, пожалуйста, или расскажите о своих способах управления конфигурациями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две популярные штуки для управления конфигурациями, не лазая на сервера по ssh, это [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/) и [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).